# How to specify the layout to render when submitting a form and validation fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my app, `new` and `edit` actions of a controller should render different templates rather than the default layout like the following (it is not a normal rails app but an engine though).

```
module Blorgh
  class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

    layout Blorgh.config.layout # Configured in initializer

    ...

    # GET /articles/new
    def new
      @article = Article.new
      render :new, layout: "blorgh/new"
    end

    # GET /articles/1/edit
    def edit
      render :edit, layout: "blorgh/edit"
    end

    ...
  end
end
```

It works as expected, but when validation failed on `POST create` or `PATCH update` action via submitting a form in `new` or `edit` page, they are rendered with the default layout.

How to specify the layout in this case?

- Ruby 2.2.0
- Rails 4.2.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your `create` and `update` methods here. Chances are you're telling them to render `new` or `edit` on failure, without also specifying the layout to use.

Comment: thank you, i should have posted them. now it's solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do it is the same as in `new` and `edit` actions:

```
def update
  # ...
  render :edit, layout: 'blorgh/edit'
end

def create
  # ...
  render :new, layout: 'blorgh/new'
end
```

BTW, in your `new` and `edit` actions, you don't have to indicate template to render manually. It's ok if you have:

```
def new
  # ...
  render layout: 'blorgh/new'
end

def edit
  # ...
  render layout: 'blorgh/edit'
end
```